# Python - How to get write the function that genrates the series with the first day of the year?

Tags: python, datetime

Iam working on the case. where i have list of the dates that represents the request closed. I want to find out total Days in that year taken to complete the request and inorder for that i need help to write down function that generates the first day of the year based request closed.

Closed Date
2018-2-10
2012-1-5
2011-1-6
2018-8-10

Comment: "generates the first day of the year based request closed". This really isn't clear, can you provide a better example of what you are trying to do? What have to attempted so far?

Comment: so what i am trying to do is have to get the first day of the year from the closed dates. e.g. is closed date is 2018-2-10. Iam trying to make separate column where correponding date will be 2018-1-1. that way i can calculate total days in that year taken to process request.  Hope that clears it

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean:

```
>>> a = date(2018, 2, 10)
>>> a
datetime.date(2018, 2, 10)
>>> b = date(a.year, 1, 1)
>>> b
datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)
```